# Pan Larger image when Thumbnail is panned

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pan

Sorry for the awful title, I wasn't sure of the correct terminology to use.

I have put a world map on a webpage with a canvas window on the image. This world map is far too large to view at once so the user can pan the image within the window.  I would like to also place a "thumbnail" version of the image on the page with a rectangle cursor over
layed on top of the thumbnail.  When the user moves the cursor over the thumbnail, the large map will move (self-pan) to match the area under the rectangle cursor on the thumbnail![enter image description here][1]

There is an example in the image provided.  You will see a small portion of a worldmap. To the right is a thumbnail of the image with a rectangle cursor.  When that cursor is moved, the world map will pan.

I am using HTML5 and javascript.  No other languages.  If someone could point me to an example or set me on the right path, I would be very grateful.

Thank yoU!

Comment: Oops!  I am a newbie so i could not upload a pic.  I will put it on a host somewhere and provide a link

Comment: Here's the link to the sample picture:   https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=160943017386281&set=a.160943010719615.37407.157725957707987&type=3&theater